# Remove "Add New" button from Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I wonder if anyone can provide a definitive answer on this, Google seems to throw up no decent answers.

I want to remove the "Add New" button from the `edit.php` screen. I have attached a screenshot so you know where I mean.

Can anyone help? Preferably programmatically, not through CSS hacks.

Cheers!

[image: Add New button]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typical, I played around for a bit and managed to achieve what I was looking for.

Navigate to `wp-admin\edit.php` and find the following code (lines 311-313 for me):

```
if ( current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->create_posts ) ) { 
  echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( $post_new_file ) ) . '" class="page-title-action">' . esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->add_new ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment out the following code:

```
// echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( $post_new_file ) ) . '" class="page-title-action">' . esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->add_new ) . '</a>';
```

Your finished code should be displayed:

```
if ( current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->create_posts ) ) {
  // echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( $post_new_file ) ) . '" class="page-title-action">' . esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->add_new ) . '</a>';
}
```

The end result is it will remove the "Add New" button from the edit.php page in admin. It will do it for everyone, regardless of privileges or roles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Never edit the Wp core.

Answer (score -2):

i think you have to make sure you can use CSS programmatically

```
function disable_new_pages() {
// Hide sidebar link   
global $submenu;
unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][10]);
if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page') {
echo '<style type="text/css">
.wrap .page-title-action { display:none; }
</style>';
}
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_new_pages');
```

Comment: Good answer but this is only relevant if you want to remove the "Add Page" link from the sidebar and it doesn't apply to the button.

Comment: what do u mean by sidebar ?? its applying to my button in all pages i dont get it